# react javascript build specific part of the code using admin, vendor roles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am doing a dashboard for admin and vendor. is it possible to build if its an admin builds this part of the code and have that option and if its a vendor builds this part of the code and have that option?

I don't want to put it this way. I think will have a security issue after that.

```
if (admin) { 

} elseif (vendor) {

}
```

Comment: Server side rendering is what I think you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is not secure at all without something on your backend enforcing whatever it is that each role specifically can and can not do.